# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity

Tags: java, jsf

Eu tenho uma classe de modelo simples de Fabricante apenas com o atributo 'descricao'. O meu banco de dados está populado e o método salvar e editar estão funcionando normalmente. Porem quando vou excluir gera no console o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity
at org.hibernate.event.spi.DeleteEvent.<init>(DeleteEvent.java:48)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896)
at br.com.drogaria.dao.GenericDAO.excluir(GenericDAO.java:48)
at br.com.drogaria.bean.FabricanteBean.excluir(FabricanteBean.java:62)
```

GenericDAO

```
public void excluir(Entidade entidade) {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = null;

    try {
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        sessao.delete(entidade);
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
        if (transacao != null) {
            transacao.rollback();
        }
        throw erro;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}
```

Classe Bean, porem a lógica de negócio futuramente irei colocar em uma classe de Service:

```
public void excluir(ActionEvent evento) {
    try {
        this.fabricante = (Fabricante) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fabricanteSelecionado");

        FabricanteDAO fabricanteDAO = new FabricanteDAO();
        //this.fabricante = fabricanteDAO.buscar(fabricante.getCodigo());

        fabricanteDAO.excluir(fabricante);
        this.fabricantes = fabricanteDAO.listar();

        Messages.addGlobalInfo("Fabricante excluído com sucesso!");
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
        Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar excluir um Fabricante.");
        erro.printStackTrace();
    }
```

xhtml

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{fabricanteBean.excluir}"
            update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela" title="Excluir">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir o Fabricante?"
        icon="ui-icon-alert">
        <f:attribute name="fabricanteSelecionado" value="#{fabricante}" />
    </p:confirm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade as classes estão corretas, conferindo depois com calma percebi que o erro estava no xhtml no confirmDialog, eu coloquei o f:attribute dentro do p:confirm, errado: E o correto é como abaixo.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{fabricanteBean.excluir}"
        update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela" title="Excluir">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir o Fabricante #{fabricante.descricao}?" 
            icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        <f:attribute name="fabricanteSelecionado" value="#{fabricante}" />
</p:commandButton>
```